# How to connect 2 views in asp.net razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How I can include and show 2 views in asp.net razor application(I don't use mvc). In package models I have cars and drivers.
In package "Pages" I create 2 folders(CarsPage, DriversPage).I generated crud (add ->new scaffolded item -> razor pages using entity).  In my database one car can only 1 drivers. I want show all cars with drivers eg.
car1 , ford, blue...drivers1 , Jon, ...
car2, Mercedes, black...., James, ...

In table cars my pk is "Id" and fk from table drivers is too "Id"
How I can do include and show all information ?
 If in my post is somethink worse please write it.

```cs
public partial class Cars
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Color{ get; set; }...
    }

public partial class Drivers
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name{ get; set; }
        public string Surename{ get; set; }...
    }


@page
@model MyApp.Pages.CarsPage.IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    <a asp-page="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>

    <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cars[0].Id)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Cars[0].Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.cars[0].Color)
            </th>

<th></th>
        </tr>


    </thead>



<tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.Cars)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color)
                </td>
<td>
                    <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route- 
 id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
```

Comment: Have you considered checking out Partial views?

Comment: Yes, but i don't know exactly how to create it

Comment: Please read it carefully https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/mvc/views/partial?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: You need to add `public Drivers Driver {get;set;}` in the car model.What is the relationship between cars and drivers?Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships?view=aspnetcore-2.1.Then pass the item.Driver as model to partial view and display the drive's info.

Comment: Thanks Peter B and Xing Zou for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the drivers' information in the partial view. Pass the `Car.Drivers` to partial view in the Index view.

You could refer to my below demo:

1.Models:

```
public class Cars
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public string DriversId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DriversId")]
    public Drivers Drivers { get; set; }
}

public class Drivers
{
    [Key]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surename { get; set; }
}
```

2.Create a `DriversPartial.cshtml` razor view not razor pages(add->New item->Razor view) in `CarsPage` folder.input what you would like to display in the partial view which receives a `Drivers` model:

```
@model Yournamespace.Drivers
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Id) :
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model .Id)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name) :
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model .Name)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Surename):
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model .Surename)
    </td>

    <td>
        <a asp-page="/DriversPage/Edit" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Edit</a> |
        <a asp-page="/DriversPage/Details" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Details</a> |
        <a asp-page="/DriversPage/Delete" asp-route-id="@Model.Id">Delete</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

3.Use partial view in `Index.cshtml`

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Cars)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Color)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Drivers.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-page="./Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-page="./Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
            <a asp-page="./Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    @await Html.PartialAsync("DriversPartial.cshtml", item.Drivers);

}
```

4.Index.cshtml.cs

```
public IList<Cars> Cars { get;set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Cars = await _context.Cars
            .Include(c => c.Drivers).ToListAsync();
    }
```

5.Result:
[image]

You could modify the partial view to add your custom page.

Comment: @Jan You are welcome.Could you accept my reply as answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to render a second "page" into your first page, you should take a look at [View Components](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2)